# What is the root reason of embed php inside image format

Tags: php

It is a while I wanted to ask why on earth there is such thing as embedding PHP code inside an image such as GIF or PNG (check [here](https://www.trustwave.com/en-us/resources/blogs/spiderlabs-blog/hiding-webshell-backdoor-code-in-image-files/) or [here](https://websec.io/2012/09/05/A-Silent-Threat-PHP-in-EXIF.html) for info), are there any historical reasons? and who use this feature?.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's not a feature, it's an exploit. Some image file formats have some meta-data headers inside the image file, to store things like the time and date the image was created, what tool (or camera) created it, etc.

Some attackers figured out that if they stuff PHP code into those image file meta-data header fields that were never designed for it, and then they get a web server to serve the file in just the right way, that the web server will be stupid enough to see the PHP code and execute it even though it's in an image file and not a PHP or HTML text file.

Comment: I asked because I could not imagine the web servers that stupid to execute PHP code inside image :-), And it is not like exploiting some buffer overflow or similar vulnerabilities I guess, that's bothering me :) .